# Mystery Font? Please help

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Hi guys can anyone find out what font this is, or something similar?
Bold, rounded serif font.[image]

(ps - 'N's are distorted because this was taken off a t-shirt.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVC-Midguard is a very close if not correct match.

It's hard to tell with the distortion from the fabric.

[image]

Comment: @Lauren Happy to help! It should be noted that it looks like the serifs have been rounded in your original image. This should be easy to do in Illustrator after you have expanded the text.